# dynamically created list of link buttons, link buttons not posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

Hi I am dynamically creating link buttons in a 'ul li' list. I am then trying to tie each  link button to a click event where i set a label to the text of the link button clicked. however the event that should fire doesnt get fired?

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
int listItemIds = 0;
       foreach (Node productcolour in product.Children)
       {
           HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
           LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
           lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds;
           lnk.Text = productcolour.Name;
           lnk.Click += new EventHandler(Clicked);
           //lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnkColourAlternative_Click);
           //lnk.Click 
           li.Controls.Add(lnk);
           ul1.Controls.Add(li);
           listItemIds++;
       }
}
```

the above is wrapped within a if(!page.ispostback) and the label text is never set anywhere else.
heres to the event

```
protected void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lno = sender as LinkButton;
    litSelectedColour.Text = lno.Text;

}
```

Comment: you need `lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Clicked);`

Comment: Are you recreating your dynamic controls on every postback with the same id as before?

Comment: tried this but it didnt work :(

Comment: no the controls are only created in page load. as noted above this is wrapped in a if(!page.ispostback).

Comment: looks like controls Id's changed on each postback. If you use asp.net 4.0 try to play with 'ClientIdMode'

Comment: hi devi, see my edits. the ids definitely dont change.

Comment: @user1238321: dynamic controls **must** be recreated on every postback due to the stateless nature of HTTP. You must ensure that they get the same ID as before so that ViewState can be reloaded and events are  triggered correctly. So **no** `!IsPostback`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code must run on each postback:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        int listItemIds = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            var lnk = new LinkButton();

            lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds;
            lnk.Text = "text" + i;
            lnk.Click += Clicked;
            //lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnkColourAlternative_Click);
            //lnk.Click 
            li.Controls.Add(lnk);
            ul1.Controls.Add(li);
            listItemIds++;
        }
    }

    private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as LinkButton;
        btn.Text = "Clicked";
    }
```

Comment: more precisely, is no needs to write if(!Postback){}, dynamically generated controls must be generated each request with same id's

Comment: I am not going to downvote this solution since "it does the job" but be aware that you may run into problems with ViewState. See this MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do this sort of thing `OnInit` and make sure you recreate the controls on every postback.

See this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794) for an example - a bit outdated but the methodology is still the same.