# how to generate a pop up aspx window when clicking on the dynamically created link button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamically generated link button. I wants to create a pop up window when  clicking on these buttons.how is it possible.

```
   foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
  {
      // now create the LinkButtons ...

      Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>"));
      LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
      lb.Text = fileName;
      lb.ID = fileName;
      Session["fn"] = fileName;
      Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
      Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
      lb.PostBackUrl = ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "New", "window.open('pdf_files.aspx');", true);


 }
```

it shows an error "cant convert string to void "

Comment: Can you post your full code ?

Comment: error is at last line  lb.PostBackUrl = ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "New", "window.open('pdf_files.aspx');", true);
@ Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: Change lb.PostBackUrl to lb.OnClick

Comment: showing the same error "cant implicitly convert void to string "  @ Ramesh Rajendran

Answer (score 0):

Change `lb.PostBackUrl` to `lb.OnClick`

try this

```
lb.**OnClick** += Clickedevent













private void Clickedevent (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "New", "window.open('pdf_files.aspx');", true);
    }
```

Comment: cant understand what is this ,lb.**OnClick** += Clickedevent ?? please help @Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485907/dynamically-created-list-of-link-buttons-link-buttons-not-posting-back